# Mutating date values inside a list and obtaining the range

Tags: r, dplyr

I am currently working with a list which contains dates in a messy format. I am trying to clean them into two columns Date/Time inside the list without having to extract the dataframe from the list. Once the days are cleaned I want to get the minimum/maximum date from the set and create a string with all the days in between.

The dates in my list have the format 2019-07-20T17:12:08+10:00 and I have been able to clean them by extracting the first dataframe from the list but not inside it, i.e:`Y <- as_tibble(X[[1]])`

```
#Clean Date Values in Y
Y <- Y %>%
  mutate(Date = str_replace_all(created_at, "T", " ")) %>%
  separate(Date, into = c("Date","Time"), sep = " ")

#Obtain the Min/Max to get date range of datasets and create a Calendar tibble
Dates <- seq(min(X$dates$Date), min(X$dates$Date), by="days")
Calendar <- as_tibble(Date)
```

What would be the best way to run the Clean Date process while retaining the information inside the list and extract the date ranges from that list?

Example Code:

```
X <- list(dates = structure(list(created_at = c("2019-06-04T13:25:57+10:00", 
"2019-06-05T06:14:29+10:00", "2019-07-09T19:20:18+10:00", "2019-07-12T11:57:28+10:00", 
"2019-07-16T01:10:49+10:00", "2019-07-20T17:12:08+10:00"), cancelled_at = c("2019-06-06T17:46:49+10:00", 
"2019-06-05T08:37:32+10:00", NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001b0851f1ef0>), 
    sent = c("T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the changed values in the list itself.

```
library(tidyverse)

X$dates <- X$dates %>%
  mutate(Date = str_replace_all(created_at, "T", " ")) %>%
  separate(Date, into = c("Date","Time"), sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date))
Dates <- seq(min(X$dates$Date), max(X$dates$Date), by="days")
X$Calendar <- as_tibble(Dates)
X

#$dates
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  created_at                cancelled_at              Date       Time          
#  <chr>                     <chr>                     <date>     <chr>         
#1 2019-06-04T13:25:57+10:00 2019-06-06T17:46:49+10:00 2019-06-04 13:25:57+10:00
#2 2019-06-05T06:14:29+10:00 2019-06-05T08:37:32+10:00 2019-06-05 06:14:29+10:00
#3 2019-07-09T19:20:18+10:00 NA                        2019-07-09 19:20:18+10:00
#4 2019-07-12T11:57:28+10:00 NA                        2019-07-12 11:57:28+10:00
#5 2019-07-16T01:10:49+10:00 NA                        2019-07-16 01:10:49+10:00
#6 2019-07-20T17:12:08+10:00 NA                        2019-07-20 17:12:08+10:00

#$sent
#[1] "T" "T" "T" "T" "T" "T"

#$Calendar
# A tibble: 47 x 1
#   value     
#   <date>    
# 1 2019-06-04
# 2 2019-06-05
# 3 2019-06-06
# 4 2019-06-07
# 5 2019-06-08
# 6 2019-06-09
# 7 2019-06-10
# 8 2019-06-11
# 9 2019-06-12
#10 2019-06-13
# … with 37 more rows
```

Comment: I did not know that! The way I was trying to go about it was way more convoluted :/ If I wanted the column Time to have the Time with the proper time zone would it be something like adding after the date mutate(Time = hms(Time, TZ=+10GMT)?

Comment: I am not sure if you can have only time with timezone. You can have it as chaarcter but that will not have timezone attribute. `ymd_hms(X$dates$created_at)` will convert the data into POSIXct format from where you can extract date and time separately.